# Redirection from filter is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

I'm trying to redirect my app to the login page in case the session has expired (I have set an interval of 60 minutes). I have created a filter but it seems the redirection is not working properly.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>RedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>LoginUtils.RedirectFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/AppUtils/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My filter:

```
@WebFilter("/AppUtils/*")
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        this.context.log("RedirectFilter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        this.context.log("Requested Resource::" + uri);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        String loginURL = req.getContextPath() + "/login.html";

        if (session == null && !req.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)) {
            this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
            res.sendRedirect(loginURL);
        } else {
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    public void destroy() {
        //no-op
    }

}
```

Comment: no need to define your filter in the `web.xml`, the annotation is enough

Comment: which `URL` to test it ? Are you sure that your filter is even called?

Comment: I'm surprised that you have to implement it, are your aware of [security constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html)?

Comment: What's the result - how does the application react if there's no session and an other page than the login page is called?

Comment: check also [login form](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gkbsa/index.html)

Comment: The filter is called but only the redirection is not been executed. The response of the filter execution results in the log: Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Requested Resource::/myapp/AppUtils/update_database
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Unauthorized access request